# IOCTL write crashing

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, ioctl

I am trying to implement ioctl in kernel space to write some date into the register, I am getting a crash in cmd of ioctl.

Below is my code:

**Kernel side:**

```
static struct file_operations fops = {
.compat_ioctl = device_ioctl
};

int device_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *filep, 
                 unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{

    int len = 200;

    printk (KERN_INFO "In Device_ioctl !!\n");
    switch(cmd)
    {
    case IOCTL_WRITE_REG:
        write_ioctl((unsigned long *)arg);
        break;

    default:
        printk (KERN_INFO "default\n");
        return -ENOTTY;
    }
    printk (KERN_INFO "device_ioctl out\n");
    return len;
}
```

**User Side**

```
#define IOCTL_WRITE_REG _IOW(MAJOR_NUM, 1, int *)
void write_to_device(int write_fd)
{

    int retval;
    unsigned int to_write1 = 1;

    retval = ioctl(write_fd, IOCTL_WRITE_REG, &to_write1);
    if(retval < 0)
    {
        printf("fd: %d, write error: %d\n", write_fd, errno);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

It is not entering into device_ioctl function,
Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You need to be using `unlocked_ioctl` instead of `compat_ioctl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things I happen to notice:

- You need to use `unlocked_ioctl` instead of `compat_ioctl`. `compat_ioctl` is to allow 32-bit user space programs to invoke `ioctl` calls on a 64-bit kernel.
- The signature of your ioctl handler function is incorrect (for `unlocked_ioctl`). The expected signature is:

  ```
  long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file * filep, unsigned int, unsigned long);
  ```

I haven't tried really compiling this code, but I think this should work:

```
static struct file_operations fops = {
    .unlocked_ioctl = device_ioctl
};

long device_ioctl(struct file *filep, 
                  unsigned int cmd,
                  unsigned long arg)
{

    int len = 200;

    printk (KERN_INFO "In Device_ioctl !!\n");
    switch(cmd)
    {
    case IOCTL_WRITE_REG:
        write_ioctl((unsigned long *)arg);
        break;

    default:
        printk (KERN_INFO "default\n");
        return -ENOTTY;
    }
    printk (KERN_INFO "device_ioctl out\n");
    return len;
}
```

Comment: can you give me a simple definition for compat_ioctl and closed_ioctl, appart from this 32-64 bit conversion ?